# Retrofit into Glide

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, retrofit, android-glide

I am using Retrofit and Glide for a simple Image and textView. In my "Description" fragment I want to display the image from the api into the ImageView just under the textView. My recyclerView images work perfectly, but how would I display a single image from the retrofit/api into this Description class.

I added

```
        val imageView:ImageView = view!!.findViewById(R.id.item_image)
```

But I am lost after this.

This is the fragment with the textview and where I want to place the ImageView under the text description

```
class DescriptionFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = DescriptionFragment()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {



        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)
    }


    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        val textView:TextView = view!!.findViewById(R.id.message)
        val imageView:ImageView = view!!.findViewById(R.id.item_image)


        // Get the arguments from the caller fragment/activity
        val description = arguments?.getString("description")
        description?.let {
            textView.text = "Description : \n$description"
        }

    }
}
```

This is the xml I would like to load the image into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.DescriptionFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
        android:text="@string/full_repo_description"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/message"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="36dp"
        android:text="DescriptionFragment"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the data class where I get the avatar_url from

```
data class owner(var avatar_url:String);
data class Items(var id: String, var name: String, var full_name: String,var description: String,var owner: owner)
```

This is my current recycler class which is working correctly

```
class RecyclerAdapter(private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    var itemList: List<Items> = listOf()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_layout, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.repoId.text = itemList[position].id
        holder.repoName.text = itemList[position].name
        holder.repoFullName.text = itemList[position].full_name

        Glide.with(context).load(itemList[position].owner.avatar_url)
            .apply(RequestOptions().centerCrop())
            .into(holder.repoImage)

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {

            val intent = Intent(context, DescriptionActivity::class.java)
            // To pass any data to next activity
            intent.putExtra("description", itemList[position].description)
            // start your next activity
            context.startActivity(intent)

            //  Toast.makeText(context,itemList.get(position).id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }

    }

    fun setItemsList(itemList: List<Items>) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!) {

        val repoId: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.item_id)
        val repoName: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.item_name)
        val repoFullName: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.item_fullname)
        val repoImage: ImageView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.item_image)


    }

}
```

And this is my current mainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    lateinit var recyclerAdapter: RecyclerAdapter

    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview)
        recyclerAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(this)
        recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = recyclerAdapter


        val apiInterface = ApiInterface.create().getItems()

        apiInterface.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Items>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Items>>?, response: Response<List<Items>>?) {

                if (response?.body() != null) {
                    Log.d("myTest", response.body().toString());
                    recyclerAdapter.setItemsList(response.body()!!)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Items>>?, t: Throwable?) {

            }
        })

    }

}
```

And the way I get my url with Retrofit

```
interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("repos")
    fun getItems() : Call<List<Items>>

    companion object {

        var BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/orgs/square/"

        fun create() : ApiInterface {

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build()
            return retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using data binding and add a binding adapter to load your image using Glide

[ UPDATE 2 ]
Consider using fixed value size for Imageview (Width and Height) when you want to show images dynamically (in this case loading from Network)

[ UPDATE ]

Look closely into your RecyclerAdapter class. You have to put the imageUrl in your Intent using this code snippet:

```
            intent.putExtra("imageUrl", itemList[position].owner.avatar_url)
```

then in your Description{Fragment/Activity} you have to get that url and let the glide do the rest:

```
val imageUrl = arguments?.getString("imageUrl")
imageUrl?.let { loadImageViaUrl(imageview, it) }
```

and define loadImageViaUrl as below :

```
private fun loadImageViaUrl(view: ImageView, url: String) {
val options = RequestOptions()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.network_image_placeholder) // use any image as placeholder

Glide.with(view.context)
    .setDefaultRequestOptions(options)
    .load(url)
    .into(view)
```

}

This is the most basic way to use the Glide library.

Comment: I have updated my classes with the layouts and classes above

Comment: @Brummerly Why you have a DescriptionActivity and DescriptionFragment at the same time? what is the purpose of each? Did you manage to get the description and show it in the textView (in DescriptionFragment)? if so then You're only problem is image not being shown, yes?

Comment: Yes the description works perfectly, its just the image I am having issues with

Comment: @Brummerly , I updated my answer, If you still have problems with loading image, just let me know :) so I can help you with that.

Comment: @Brummerly : one more thing, You are doing good ... but your code can be refactored and be more readable :) , I recommend you reading some articles about <Android Clean Architecture> It helps you write maintainable codes, and reduce lots of complexity :)